# Join tables on dates, with dirty date field

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, date, join

In AWS Athena, I am trying to join two tables in the db using the date, but one of the tables (table2) is not clean, and contains values that are not dates, as shown below.

```
| table2.date |
| ---- |
|6/02/2021|
|9/02/2021|
|1431 BEL & 1628 BEL."|
|15/02/2021|
|and failed to ....|
|18/02/2021|
|19/02/2021|
```

I am not able to have any influence in cleaning this table up.

My current query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table1.operation_date = cast(date_parse(table2."date",'%d/%m/%Y') as date)
LIMIT 10;
```

I've tried using `regex_like(col, '[a-z]')`, but this still leaves the values that are numerical, but not dates.

How do I get the query to ignore the values that are not dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wrap conversion expression with `try` function, that will resolve to `NULL` in case of failed conversion.

```
select
  try(date_parse(col, '%d/%m/%Y'))
from(values
  ('6/02/2021'),
  ('9/02/2021'),
  ('1431 BEL & 1628 BEL.'),
  ('15/02/2021'),
  ('and failed to ....'),
  ('18/02/2021'),
  ('19/02/2021')
) as t(col)
```

| # | _col0 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-06 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2021-02-09 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 |  |
| 4 | 2021-02-15 00:00:00.000 |
| 5 |  |
| 6 | 2021-02-18 00:00:00.000 |
| 7 | 2021-02-19 00:00:00.000 |